# Alamofire, Updated data on server is not updating on response

Tags: swift, alamofire, response

Here is my alamofire code.

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json",
                                "Authorization": Setting.getLoginStatus().accessToken]
    let url = "http://thedemo.net/demo/stdinaus/api/jobs-near-me?page=1&latitude=27.6947033&longitude=85.3310636"

Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, encoding : JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        guard let jobsResponse = response.result.value as? [String:Any] else{
            print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
            failure((response.result.error! as Error))
            return
        }
            print("response: \(jobsResponse)") }
```

Response is coming properly and displayed on related screen. I've call this from viewDidLoad() in view controller. When data is updated on server the new data doesn't appear on the response. But if I delete the app and run again (i.e. if app is running for the first time) then the updated data is coming properly.

**Is that a problem with alamofire code? Please someone help me with this issue. Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be issue with cache data, so ignore it when you calling the API.

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.requestCachePolicy = . reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

var req = URLRequest(url: URL(string: YOUR_API_URL)!)
req.httpMethod = "GET"
req.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
req.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
req.setValue(Setting.getLoginStatus().accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField:"Authorization" )
req.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

Alamofire.request(req).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
    }
```

Comment: I paste the above code before Alamofire block. Still not working.

Comment: still not working. Once I delete the app and run again then latestly added data is appearing on json response.

Comment: Thank you Rocky. The problem was related to caching. But URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses() This code worked for me. Do alamofire caches the data automatically?

Answer (score 0):

so if I understand correctly, you want the data in your app to be updated as soon as when it is updated in your server?

If this is the case, you shouldn't be calling it in viewDidLoad() method because this method is **only called once** when your view loads. It wont be called again until you restart your app.

Comment: No that is not the problem. When I pop back to another screen and again go to the related screen then the alamofire block of code is executed and response is also displaying. But latest updated data in server is not on the response. But if I delete the app ani run again updated data will appear on response.

Comment: then its the problem of backend rather then your end

Comment: "When I pop back to another screen and again go to the related screen then the alamofire block of code is executed and response is also displaying." you mean when you switched to another view in your app and then switch back to your view with the api call the data is updated? i.e. a tab bar with tab A (with api call) and tab B (no api call). Your data is updated when you switch from A to B then back to A?

Comment: as @NischalHada said you might want to work with Realtime database to see the immediate update

Comment: @John Doe - If someone add one data on server then the postman response is showing the last added data also. But in xcode when I call api for second time then there'll be no last added data. Even running the app is not fetching the latest data. But is fetching the latest data if I delete the app and run again.

Comment: @Sptibo 1.) How are you calling the APi the second time? Are you displaying the data in a tableview or something? 2.) Delete the app do you mean closing the app (ie double tapping on the home button and then swipe from bottom to top to kill the app) or delete the actual app and reinstalling?

Comment: I'm displaying the data in tableview. Deleting the app means long press the app icon and tap on cross botton. Only closing the app is not updating the latest data.

Comment: @Sptibo so if you have tried closed app -> update data in server -> reopen app and the data is not being updated, then most likely it is the problem with the server because as far as I can tell the code you've posted seem fine. However, please do check if you have tried the method tableview.reload() after you've finished calling the api

Comment: yes i've reload the tableview. data is not appearing with latest update if I print("response: \(response.result.value)")

Comment: @Sptibo then I think it should be the problem from the server and not your app assuming if I understood what you were saying. Check the api documentation to see if it has anything about how often you can make the call to the api within a given time period because this might be the case